# Book about a warlock who fears fire

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I'm looking for a book I read a long time ago. It would have been a children's fantasy novel as I read it around the age of 8-10. I don't remember much about the plot other than that the antagonist was a warlock who lived deep in a rotting forest, which he kept under constant rain for fear of fire. When the protagonist finally confronts the warlock, he figures out that the warlock is afraid of fire and throws a torch at him, which quickly burns him to ash and breaks the rain spell.

I believe that the reason the protagonist goes into the woods is that the warlock kidnapped one of their friends, so he goes to get her back. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: On your edit, can you remember why the warlock kidnaps one of the friends?

Answer (score 6):

I’m a few years late because I was just searching for the answer to this and stumbled across your post. I spent several hours looking and finally found it!

It’s called ***[The Eye of the Warlock](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SGb350IG2rEC&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=1#v=onepage&q&f=false)*** (2005) by P.W. Catanese.

It’s a retelling of *Hansel and Gretel*. He actually did a series of fairy tale retellings, some of the titles are *The Brave Apprentice*, *The Riddle of the Gnome*, and *The Thief and the Beanstalk*. I’ve read them before when I was a kid, and from what I can remember, the twists are just as good. Hope that helps!

Regarding the plot, the warlock kidnaps the protagonist’s two little sisters and he searches the forest for them, knowing the local legends surrounding two children from years ago known as Hansel and Gretel. The warlock keeps his castle in constant rain with a moat surrounding it. The protagonist realises his aversion to fire/flames and discovers that is the warlock’s weakness.

Comment: Could you explain how this matches the OP's description of the book they were looking for? It'd help other users determine how likely this is to be the correct answer.

Comment: The warlock kidnaps the protagonist’s two little sisters and he searches the forest for them knowing the local legends surrounding two children from years ago known as Hansel and Gretel. The warlock keeps his castle in constant rain with a moat surrounding it. The protagonist realises his aversion to fire/flames and discovers that is the warlock’s weakness. Here’s a link to the book: https://books.google.com.au/books/about/The_Eye_of_the_Warlock.html?id=SGb350IG2rEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gb_mobile_entity&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&gboemv=1&gl=AU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help :)